# объём полученных данных по каждому запросу

Tags: jmeter, report

В листенере jmeter "Summary report" имеется такой столбец, как объём полученных данных в KB/sec - т.е. скорость.
Есть ли какой-либо листенер, или иной способ, чтоб получить не скорость, а именно объём полученных данных по каждому запросу в KB?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: summary report чего???

Comment: вопрос максимально не понятный, вы я надеюсь понимаете что пользователи данного ресурса находятся в некотором отдалении от вас и того что у вас происходит на мониторе)

Comment: Summary Report отчётная форма в jmeter. В этот листенере есть столбик "Received KB/sec" - т.е. скорость передачи данных. Мой вопрос заключается в том, есть ли в jmeter листенер или другое средство, чтоб получить не "Received KB/sec", а "Received KB"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решён. Нужную информацию даёт Listener "View Results in Table"

Answer (score 0):

В будущем пожалуйста, описывайте свой вопрос более подробно, так же не забывайте использовать теги.

Совершенно не понятно о чем именно вы спрашиваете, о какой технологии, о скорости чего?

Так же не ясно, что такое Summary report.

Из интернета Summary report - это:

> Summary report - это короткое письменное сообщение, которое может иметь
> множество целей, например: Информировать читателя о деталях
> конкретного события. Чтобы проанализировать ту или иную проблему,
> сделать выводы и дать рекомендации. Убедить читателя в важности того
> или иного образа действий.

Разве вы сами смогли бы ответить на вопрос другого человека с подобной формулировкой?

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснения. Вопрос поправил. Прошу не судить строго новичка...